# Datacenter with fast connectivity to AWS Virgina (S3 data exchange)

Tags: amazon-s3, colocation, amazon-web-services

I'm looking for a colo with a fast connection and low latency to the Amazon Web Services Virginia location. I need fast connectivity to S3 with reasonable pricing for a server that can handle CPU intense tasks (i5/i7 preferably).

Any ideas?

thanks
mat

Answer (score 1):

I know from experience that Equinix http://www.equinix.com/ has Virginia locations with extremely fast performance to S3.

Comment: What's your read/write throughput with them?

Comment: Gigabits per second, certainly.  How many?  We haven't exhaustively checked.